# How can we pass headers in PutObjectRequest as to upload S3 bucket

Tags: java, sdk, aws-sdk

How can we set header PutObjectRequest in  for sdk java 2.x version.

In 1.11.x version, we have below code:

```
ObjectMetadata md = new ObjectMetadata();
md.setHeader("Vary", "Accept-Encoding");
md.setCacheControl("max-age=680400");
md.setContentType("application/x-javascript");
```

In 2.10.x version, we have:

```
PutObjectRequest req =PutObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName).key(key)
                    .cacheControl("max-age=680400").contentType("application/x-javascript")
                    .build();
```

How can we set md.setHeader("Vary", "Accept-Encoding"); in PutObjectRequest?
could you help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do req.setMetadata(md);